# ntpd Stratum Zero when nptd is started

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I have noticed that when I start ntpd on a server, checks against that server reveal that it has a stratum of zero. If I understand this correctly, I believe this means that ntpd is currently only using itself as the time source.

After a minute or so, it checks against the server, and the stratum is no longer zero.

Do I understand this correctly, and can I speed up time the time before it becomes non-zero?

Comment: In your ntp configuration, there should be a "local clock" reference. What is the stratum listed there?

Comment: That isn't in the ubuntu server default configs.

Comment: Interesting. The CentOS/RHEL config has two servers configured with "server 127.1271.0 stratum 10". Looking at that again, I'm pretty sure it doesn't change the behavior you're talking about.

Comment: OK, mine defaults to stratum 16 when it's in the initial startup. What ntp server are you running?

Comment: Guys, clearly the part that Kyle left out is that he's got his server hooked up to a TARDIS.

Comment: @Phil that would make sense since a TARDIS is probably a stratum -1 clock (capable of changing the time of the universe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *sounds* like a bug (or a configuration edit gone horribly wrong) - As Matt Simmons pointed out ntpd usually defaults to Stratum 16 ("Unsynchronized").

My (admittedly limited) understanding of NTP strata is that Stratum 0 is reserved for reference clocks (a cesium clock for example, or a GPS Time receiver) that you would attach to a computer to create a stratum 1 server (using the stratum 0 device as its reference).

Comment: Hmm... could be the Nagios check_ntp_time gone wrong as well....

Comment: Could be - I'm not sure how good the Nagios NTP stuff is.  What does `ntpq -c readlist` show as the stratum?

Comment: @vortaq7: It shows 16, so apparently it is this program being silly.

Answer (score 0):

Local clock should not be used.

you can speed up synchronization by using the iburst keyword for your server definitions.